# How to add delay to a Promise resolve? Add delay to node http.request promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, settimeout

Trying to add a small delay to each http.request in NodeJS but of course node always goes in sync mode. So the question is how do I reset the state of a promise once it's been fulfilled?

1. Currently **helper.delay() works only once** in the beginning then all http requests are sent instantly, causing the server to error out.
2. Why am I not able to use **this.delay()** on other promises **inside** my module.exports? But it works fine inside normal exportable functions.
3. Off Topic. How to switch http to https depending on URL requested?
   (without copying the same code, eliminating redundancy).

*Tried the default set timeout inside the promise, wrapped http.request with a new setTimeout promise, tried using an external "requestHandler" as a callback, which was running the function as a thennable. etc.etc
Perhaps I have to **clearTimeout**?* https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

**exports**

```js
const wait = require("util").promisify(setTimeout);
module.exports = {
    delay: async function(seconds){
        await wait(seconds * 1000);
    },
    getUrl: function(url){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const options = new URL(url);
            const resolver = http.request(options, res => {
                res.setEncoding("utf8");
                let responseBody = '';
                res.on("data", body => {
                    responseBody += body
                });
                res.on('end', () => resolve(responseBody));                
            });
            resolver.end();
        });
    }
};
```

**app**

```js
const helper = require("./exports.js");
async function getdata(url) {
    const data = await help.getUrl(url);
    let results = JSON.parse(data);
    results = results.answer;
    return results;
}
function fetchData(el, i) {
    getdata(el).then(
        answer => { console.log(answer)},
        //...etc
        )
}
function getLinksFromFile(file) {
    helper.readFile(file)
        .then(arr => {
            arr.forEach((el, i) => {
            /////////ISSUE HERE BELOW//////////////
                helper.delay(4).then(() => {
                ////It only waits once
                    return fetchData(el, i);
                });
            });
        });
}
getLinksFromFile("./links.txt");
```

The objective is as simple as it can get, read urls form file, get json data from the url's and do stuff. **Dependency Free**

Comment: maybe you could use something like a queue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-queue or simpler do each request after the previous one finished. so instead of `arr => { arr.forEach` one could use `async (arr) => {.... for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ await fetchData(arr[i], i); } ...`

Comment: Thanks Roland, I could solve this instantly with packages but I'm kinda allergic to dependencies ;)
Also, everything is async on my exports, what I published was a mini version so people would click away. I wrote the functions just to ask for help and so it would be easier to understand. Still cant find an online example for http.request with a handler and setTimeout. Its so easy to do it if it's not a promise, I'll probably end up using some request/got/superagent caller for no reason. Thanks NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some more reading about how promises work or do some more experiments with Promises, to understand them better.

So what does this code do:

```
 arr.forEach((el, i) => {
            /////////ISSUE HERE BELOW//////////////
                helper.delay(4).then(() => {
                ////It only waits once
                    return fetchData(el, i);
                });
            });
```

You iterate over each element of `arr` and for each of them you create a Promise for the delay using `helper.delay(4)`. But all of those Promises are created at roughly the same time (just some nanoseconds apart), because the forEach does not wait for the one Promise chain to be finished. So each `fetchData` is delay by 4second form the time when `forEach` happened.

The easiest way to solve that problem is to convert your code to use `await`/`async` syntax:

```
async function getLinksFromFile(file) {
    let arr = await helper.readFile(file);
    for( let i=0, i<arr.length ; i++) {
        let el = arr[i];
        await helper.delay(4)
        await fetchData(el, i)
    }
}
```

Using `await` in a regular loop will pause the loop at that point until the Promise is resolved.

Comment: You can't use await in regular functions .`getLinksFromFile` needs to be async like this `async function getLinksFromFile(file){}`

Comment: Tried that multiple times, my IDE marks it red instantly when I put await there. Yes everything is async. Using this specifically https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator also FYI, everything is working fine besides the timeout. It ran 329 http calls in 2 sec, 8 failures, 6 of which were genuine, 2 were missed. Regardless, had never spent so many hours on a setTimeout before and still no results. Maybe I should Promise All or figure out how to make delay() renewable.

Comment: @JsEveryDay sorry forgot the `async` keyword, you always need to add that if you want to use `await`.

Comment: @JsEveryDay `Promise.all` would be the correct way to work with Promises without breaking the Promise chain (which happens in your case), but it still results in the same problem, as the `forEach` approach. The reason for this is that you pass a list of already created Promises to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Tried async too, only waits once. But I haven't tried for looping yet, that might work. Issue is this is 1 giant function as I have it, everything is nested in thennables, I only split it up for publishing it here. Whats weird is that the promise remains fulfilled and never tries again wheres fetchdata works fine but thats due to the url being different everytime, which led me to believe its the timing. So I tried 2 delays in sequence with different args, one 4 and one 3, that worked. If they are both 4 it only works once. So weird. Thank you tho!